# A very small big riddle ..?

Tags: riddle

> If you see through me in one direction I make it big.
>
> If you see through me in another direction I make it small.

**What am I?**

Comment: `if(question.isTooBroad()){ question.setCorrectAnswer(randomAnswer) }` (pseudocode)

Comment: @lois6b I don't think the question is too broad (all the answers are basically "magnifying lens"), just too easy.

Answer (score 4):

Could be

> A telescope

But could also be

> binoculars, magnifying glass...

So

> Anything with a lens